# How to check if you're at the end of a loop?

Tags: jquery

after some researching I can't seem to find any information to check if you're at the end of a loop. I particularly want to find out if you can check for this using the .each() in jQuery. What I want to achieve is

```
$("tr#row"+formIdentifier).find('td').each(function (){
    if (last_item_in_loop){
        alert("this is the last item in the loop");
    }
});
```

So far it loops through alright, I just want to be able to alert to the user that they're at the last item. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What a proud proof that using jQuery for everything is not always making things simple.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why last selector is not use instead of looping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, you'll have to iterate over the items yourself and check for the last index.  If you want to do it after you've processed the last element you can just add your code below the loop of course...

```
var elements = $("tr#row"+formIdentifier).find('td');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (i == elements.length - 1) {
        alert("this is the last item in the loop");
    }
    // normal stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. This has helped me continue on! Thank you evryone else for your suggestions too!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("tr#row"+formIdentifier).find('td').length` to get count

```
$("tr#row"+formIdentifier).find('td').each(function (index,value){

    if(index ==  $("tr#row"+formIdentifier).find('td').length)
     .....................
});
```

Comment: and `each` callback arguments to get current number.

Comment: each gives you the iteration index

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple condition like this

```
var $tds = $("tr#row"+formIdentifier).find('td');
var $last = $tds.last();
$tds.each(function (){
    if ($last.is(this)){
        alert("this is the last item in the loop");
    }
});
```

or using an index condition

```
var $tds = $("tr#row"+formIdentifier).find('td').each(function (idx){
    if (idx == $tds.length - 1){
        alert("this is the last item in the loop");
    }
});
```

Comment: this is probably not so good, since .last() is not cached and recomputed on every loop...

Comment: the simple condition now becomes much less simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
var elements = $('td', 'tr#row' + formIdentifier),
    total    = elements.length;

for (var i = 0; i<total; i++) {
    if (i === (total-1)) {
        alert("this is the last item in the loop");
    }
}
```